# Update contact info on Android < 2.0

Tags: java, android

I would like to get contact by name, and after that be able to check and update all information in it. Is there any example on that matter, because I couldn't find one that shows that in whole.

tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ContactContracts Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) and this [tutorial](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/2/).  Also check into the `AuthenticatorActivity` and 'ContactManager' example in the api's.